# Imagick Text is Overwriting Each Frames

Tags: php, imagick

I've created this imagick php code to create my own images in gif format.
All the code is perfect except one thing. The last text (date) is overwriting the title text. Can someone figure this out?

The result for what i've build is like this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the code from that

```
        ob_clean();
        $text=ucfirst('Title Name');
        $image = new Imagick('1.gif'); 

        $draw = new ImagickDraw(); 
        $frameCount = 0;
        foreach($image as $frame){
        $image->setImageDelay((($frameCount % 40) * 40));

        $draw->setGravity (Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST);
        $draw->setTextAlignment(Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);

        $imgSize   = $image->getImageGeometry();
        $imgHeight = $imgSize['height']; 
        $imgWidth = $imgSize['width'];
        // Calculate size
        $textProperties = array( 'textWidth' => 0 );
        $textDesiredWidth = intval( $imgWidth * 0.9 );

        $defaultFontSize = 25;
        $fontSize = 0;
        $draw->setFillColor('white'); 
        /* Font properties */
        $draw->setFont('assets/fonts/EX.ttf'); 
        while ( $textProperties['textWidth'] <= $textDesiredWidth ) {
            $draw->setFontSize( $fontSize );
            $textProperties = $image->queryFontMetrics( $draw, $text );
            $fontSize++;
        }

        if($fontSize>$defaultFontSize){
            $draw->setFontSize( $defaultFontSize );
            $centerY = floor( ($imgHeight) / 3.3 );
        }else{
            $centerY = floor( ($imgHeight) / 3.6 );
        }
        $centerX = intval( ($imgWidth) / 2 );
        $image->annotateImage( $draw, $centerX, $centerY, 0, $text );
```

As you can see that the date ('58 days ago') is overwriting the text "PAYING" from the gif image

anyone can help me figure this out?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix.!!

First we need to know the height of images then reverse the Y position

```
$imgHeight/1
```

and put in the correct position.